# Multi post thumbnails doesn't return anything

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am using the multi post thumbnails plugin. I have a custom post type "artist" who has a logo. In the loop I want to echo out the following:

```
$logo = MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_id('artist', 'Logo', $post->ID);
echo $logo;
```

Nothing gets returned - I used a `var_dump` on $logo to check, it is just an empty string. `$post->ID` returns the right id, and the parameters `artist` and `Logo` should be correct, too.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Quick suggestion: Have you checked cases? Should 'Logo' possibly be lower-case?

Answer (score 1):

First check if the post has a thumbnail:

```
$has_thumbnail = MultiPostThumbnails::has_post_thumbnail( 'artist', 'Logo', $post->ID );
```

If the post has no thumbnail, maybe you don't have attached a thumbnail to the post.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - var_dumping $has_thumbnail leaves me with an empty string as well. Is there something I am forgetting?

Comment: It seems so. Please check if the plugin is correctly installed, read the plugin documentation and check if all needed steps was correctly done, turn on debugging (WP_DEBUG = TRUE) and look out for errors, etc. There are thousands of possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

```
$logo = MultiPostThumbnails::get_the_post_thumbnail('artist', 'artist-logo', NULL, 'artist-logo');
```

It was clearly a matter of the right parameters. The second one has to refer to the thumbnail description in my functions.php, the third one has to be NULL, and the last one needs to be the same as the second one.

Thanks for your help!